# How to share modules installed on anaconda with different python versions?

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed pandas and numpy with anaconda 3.8.8. Is it possible to use this modules in the default Mac python version 3.8.2 or do I have to install them again?
Best,
Dawid

Comment: I am not sure, but I've had the same problem on my mac, but I simply just installed them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda is a different installation than your system Python.

So yes, you'll have to reinstall them (but that's simply `pip install numpy pandas`, though it'd be a great idea to use virtualenvs).